# Is there any way to change settings of my Nikon D5200 through my smart phone?

Tags: smartphone, wireless, nikon-d5200

I am using Nikon D5200
Now I can just take photos by using Nikon WMU application
Is there any app or method that I can change the settings of my camera from my (android) smart phone ?

Answer (score 1):

There was an excellent app called Qdslrdashboard.
But I do not know how to get it.
http://dslrdashboard.info/qdslrdashboard-v0-2-6/

It controls a lot of things from an android smartphone

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DR0K_-4uICA

Answer (score 0):

yes, download the app from play store I.e dslrdashboard. To connect android with dslr you need an OTG cable. There are also some paid apps if you want better control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a device such as a CamRanger, or CASE Remote. They are basically wireless routers that connect to the cameras hotshoe. They are pretty expensive though.

http://www.caseremote.com/

http://camranger.com/